# How do I properly indent long lines of code?

Tags: discussion, support, markdown, code-formatting

I saw code like this in another question:

```
mockStatic(DockerRestClient.class);
ObjectMapper obj=EasyMock.createMock(ObjectMapper.class);
expect(DockerRestClient.doGet(EasyMock.isA(String.class))).andReturn(containerData);
expect(obj.readValue(EasyMock.isA(String.class),EasyMock.same(Container.class))).andReturn(container);
//EasyMock.replay(obj);
```

Thing is: I wanted to *further* indent these lines with two spaces, to differentiate them from the method name. But it seems that somehow those lines with `expect` are messed up - when I put the cursor on "e" in expect and start typing spaces, the line starts moving *down*.

If the answer is in [how do i format my code blocks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) ... then I couldn't spot it there. In any case it would be nice to understand what exactly is going on here.

Comment: Looks unrelated. Just keep adding spaces and there won't be any extra linebreaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is going to next line because there is no white space in the line. So if you want to add space to such lines, place the cursor before `e`, press the left arrow one time so that the upcoming space will be separated by a white space with the code(already intended with 4 spaces).  Then add spaces as you want.

```
mockStatic(DockerRestClient.class);
ObjectMapper obj=EasyMock.createMock(ObjectMapper.class);
   expect(DockerRestClient.doGet(EasyMock.isA(String.class))).andReturn(containerData);
   expect(obj.readValue(EasyMock.isA(String.class),EasyMock.same(Container.class))).andReturn(container);
//EasyMock.replay(obj);
```

Comment: Nice and easy. Thanks.